# Read complex types from wsdl in java

Tags: java, parsing, xsd, wsdl, soa

I'm havving a bit of a trouble finding some way to read the complex types from a wsdl in my Java app. I'm using WSDL4J but it doesn't seem to help me get the complex types. Is there a better lib for this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 6 includes JAX-WS RI (the JAX-WS Reference Implementation). Just use `wsimport` to generate the Java artifacts from the WSDL:

```
wsimport -d generated http://example.org/stock?wsdl
```

And create a web service client using them (see [this example](http://www.javadb.com/create-a-web-service-client-with-jax-ws)).

Answer (score 0):

I would just use NetBeans. Create a new Web Service Client, give it the WSDL and you're off and running.